# How to iterate over List in List

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am solving a problem. Initially, I have to check what are the elements in this. So, how should I iterate over it????

```
//Complete the freqQuery function below.
static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries){

}
```

Comment: Please don't add links to your question.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for phrasing your question in a better way which can attract answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a foreach to take one by one the lists of integer, and, inside it, use another foreach to take all the integers:

```
for(List<Integer> lst : queries) {
   for (Integer i : lst) {
       System.out.println(i);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static List<Integer> freqQuery(List<List<Integer>> queries) {
      queries.forEach(
            query-> query.forEach(
                         integer->/*do whatever you want*/ )
                     );
}
```